# How to form a correct MySQL connection string?

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection

I am using C# and I am trying to connect to the MySQL database hosted by `00webhost`.

I am getting an error on the line `connection.Open()`:

> there is no MySQL host with these parameters.

I have checked and everything seems to be okay.

```cs
string MyConString = "SERVER=mysql7.000webhost.com;" +
            "DATABASE=a455555_test;" +
            "UID=a455555_me;" +
            "PASSWORD=something;";

MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);

MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
MySqlDataReader Reader;

command.CommandText = "INSERT Test SET lat=" + 
OSGconv.deciLat + ",long=" + OSGconv.deciLon;

connection.Open();
Reader = command.ExecuteReader();

connection.Close();
```

What is incorrect with this connection string?

Comment: Is there a typo in the site name or the connection string?

Comment: Does printing `MyConString` look correct in the debugger?

Comment: I think you should use command.executenonquery instead of reader = command.ExecuteReader(); And about your sqlcommand ,I Think it should be 'Insert Into Test(lat,long) Values ('"+OSGconv.deciLat+"','"+OSGconv.deciLon+"')'

Comment: @Hiren can you give me an example of how to write this? thanks

Comment: @p.campbell error is on the Open command

Comment: login to your control panel at webhost and check if there is a maintanance on your mysql server. sometimes they are having problems with sql servers.

Comment: Is there maybe problem if I have mysql 6 connector installed and the database is mysql 5.1?

Comment: is your mysql server remote accesible or does it have only local access

Comment: I dont know it is free hosting page. I thinkit os accesibe

Comment: try connecting with a mysql client to see if you can access it.

Comment: I have installed workbench and tried my server locally and it is working. So problem is in the host server. Thanks all!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

try creating connection string this way:

```
MySqlConnectionStringBuilder conn_string = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
conn_string.Server = "mysql7.000webhost.com";
conn_string.UserID = "a455555_test";
conn_string.Password = "a455555_me";
conn_string.Database = "xxxxxxxx";

using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conn_string.ToString()))
using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{    //watch out for this SQL injection vulnerability below
     cmd.CommandText = string.Format("INSERT Test (lat, long) VALUES ({0},{1})",
                                    OSGconv.deciLat, OSGconv.deciLon);
     conn.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I am still getting : Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Answer (score 6):

```
string MyConString = "Data Source='mysql7.000webhost.com';" +
"Port=3306;" +
"Database='a455555_test';" +
"UID='a455555_me';" +
"PWD='something';";
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example:

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(
    "Server=ServerName;Database=DataBaseName;UID=username;Password=password");

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(
    " INSERT Into Test (lat, long) VALUES ('"+OSGconv.deciLat+"','"+
    OSGconv.deciLon+"')", con);

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: At least for C#, it's Server and not ServerName