# MySQL connection string not working

Tags: c#, mysql

I have the following connection string:

`Data Source=localhost;UserID=root;Password=;Database=eyebus;`

When I try to connect  to the database I get an error saying that maybe the server was not found or not accessible. What is the problem with this string,?

I also tried other strings/words I found on the Internet, but none of them actually worked.

Also, the problem is not the server, since it can be accessed by other applications.

```
class SQLManager
    {

        private static string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ToString();


        public List<PesquisaOcorrenciasExistentesModel> getOcorrencias()
        {
            List<PesquisaOcorrenciasExistentesModel> ocorrencias = new List<PesquisaOcorrenciasExistentesModel>();

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
                using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ocorrencias", con))
                {
                    SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        PesquisaOcorrenciasExistentesModel o = new PesquisaOcorrenciasExistentesModel();
                        o.IdOcorrencia = reader.GetInt16(0);
                        o.IdOcorrenciaTipo = reader.GetInt16(1);
                        o.DataInicio = reader.GetDateTime(2);
                        o.DataFim = reader.GetDateTime(3);
                        o.Operador = reader.GetString(4);
                        o.Motorista = reader.GetString(5);
                        o.Cobrador = reader.GetString(6);
                        o.Terceiros = reader.GetString(7);
                        o.Descricao = reader.GetString(8);
                        o.EmailsEnviados = reader.GetString(9);
                        o.TipoOcorrenciaOutro = reader.GetString(10);
                        ocorrencias.Add(o);
                    }
                }
            }

            return ocorrencias;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What database connection provider are you using?

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505952/mysql-connection-string-is-not-working-in-c-sharp

Comment: MySql.Data.MySqlClient. I had already seen that post, but the presented solution didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Server` instead of Data Source, and `UID` instead of UserID.

Or check out this post, with more information: [How to form a correct MySQL connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505952/mysql-connection-string-is-not-working-in-c-sharp)

Also, don't you need to use:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString
```

And, `SqlConnection`, `SqlDataReader`, and `SqlCommand` are used for Micrsoft SQL.  I believe you should be using `MySqlConnection`, `MySqlDataReader`, and `MySqlCommand`.

Take a look at: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL

Comment: Already checked this post. Also, the string replacement suggested didn't work.

Comment: Is MySQL running on the default port (3306)?

Comment: Yes, the service is running on port 3306.

Comment: Yes it solved my problem, the problem was that I was using the wrong classes, which as you stated are used for the Microsoft's MySQL