# MySQL Connection String C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I've this error:

**"ObdcException was unhandled by user code"**

[image]

I dont know why this...

This is the connection string:

```
<add name="MiniBoxConnection" connectionString="DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Database=DATABASENAME;Server=SERVERNAME;UID=USER;PWD=PASS;"/>
```

how can i solve this problem?

i'm developing in the localhost, but database is online

**The name of the data source was not found and there was no default driver specified**

Comment: so stuff in a try/catch block, catche the exception, and see what it says.

Comment: Would you mind translating the rest of the error message into English?

Comment: show your actual code so that we can see do not paste an image please

Comment: take a look at this links as well your connection string looks a bit off https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/ or 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505952/c-how-to-form-a-correct-mysql-connection-string

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are attempting to connect to your MySQL database from your .net code using ODBC. Your error message is telling you that you haven't created an appropriately named ODBC data source object (DSN). You can do that with the ODBC Data Source Adminstrator control panel if you need to.

If I were you I would use Connector/NET instead of ODBC. It performs better and it isn't quite such a pain in the neck to configure correctly.

You can download the install kit for it here. http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

You'll need to change your code for this. But, it's worth it! Seriously! Your code will end up looking like this.

```
using System;
//etc etc
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
//etc etc

namespace myapp
{
    class Myclass
    {
        static void Mymethod(string[] args)
        {
            string connStr = "server=server;user=user;database=db;password=*****;";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
            conn.Open();

            string sql = "SELECT this FROM that";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            using (MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                while (rdr.Read()) {
                    /* iterate once per row */
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this to connect and test your connection:

```
MySqlConnectionStringBuilder conn_string = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
conn_string.Server = "127.0.0.1";
conn_string.UserID = "sa";
conn_string.Password = "myPassword";
conn_string.Database = "myDatabase";


MySqlConnection MyCon = new MySqlConnection(conn_string.ToString());


try
{
    MyCon.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("Open");
    MyCon.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Close");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```