# how do i connect to mysql database using c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

how do i connect to Mysql database using c#?

i have this code

```
entstring MyConnection = "server=localhost; port=3306; databae=database_name; uid=root;pwd=;sslMode=None; ;
```

Comment: You can find thousands of guide for this. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking.

Comment: Quite broad, you could use ODBC, OLEDB, MySQL .NET connector... Have you tried anything besides writting the connection string?

Comment: i was just trying to get my code out cause i struggled with it during my project...my connection wasnt working cause my sslMode wasn't indicated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to MySQL Database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618015/how-to-connect-to-mysql-database)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Connection String C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651318/mysql-connection-string-c-sharp)

Comment: Start by fixing the spelling mistake: databae=database

Answer (score 1):

First download `MySql.Data` package from nuget package manager then add namespace

```
//Add MySql Library
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

Connection Code-

```
string connString = "server=server;user=user;database=db;password=*****;";
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connString);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is an idea .

```
string MyConnection = "server=localhost; port=3306; databae=database_name; uid=root;pwd=;sslMode=None; ;

string Query =  "INSERT INTO table_name(username,password)VALUES('"+textbox_name.Text+"','"+password_name.Password+"');
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection);
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(Query,con);
con.open();
try{
command.ExcuteNonQuery();
```

}

```
    catch(Expection ex)
```

{

```
MessageDialog box = new MessageDialog(ex.ToString());
box.ShowAsync();
```

}

```
con.close();
```

}