# Connecting to mysql on 000webhost using C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Im simply just trying to read what there is in the batabase on to a console but i always get an exception on the conn.Open() line. Here is all the code:

```
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder conn_string = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

        conn_string.DataSource = "mysql14.000webhost.com"; // Server 
        conn_string.UserID = "a7709578_codecal";
        conn_string.Password = "xxxxx";
        conn_string.InitialCatalog = "a7709578_codecal"; // Database name

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conn_string.ToString());

        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select name FROM Users");
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{1}, {0}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
        }

        reader.Close();
        conn.Close();

        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: What's the exception? Post that as well.

Comment: The `Sql*` classes are for Microsoft SQL Server. What sort of driver do you have for MySQL - an ADO.NET one? That will have its own classes. ODBC? Then you should use the OdbcConnection.

Comment: You are not using a proper drivers cheeck it here.. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-connection.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to build the connection string manually or use `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder`. MySql uses a different format than SQL Server and the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` that you're using. You also need to use a MySQL library, `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, etc are all build specifically for SQL Server.

[MySQL connectors](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/)

Answer (score 1):

For `MySQL` database you are using wrong provider. Those classes you have used in posted code are for `SQL Server`. Your code should look like below with `MySQL` provider related classes

```
MySqlConnectionStringBuilder conn_string = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
conn_string.Server = "mysql14.000webhost.com";
conn_string.UserID = "a7709578_codecal";
conn_string.Password = "xxxxxxx";
conn_string.Database = "a7709578_codecal";

using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conn_string.ToString()))
```

Check [Related post in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505952/c-how-to-form-a-correct-mysql-connection-string)

Also to point out, you are selecting only one column from your table as can be seen

```
new SqlCommand("Select name FROM Users");
```

Whereas trying to retrieve two column value, which is not correct

```
Console.WriteLine("{1}, {0}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

000webhost free servers does not allow external connections to the server database.

You can only use your database from your PHP scripts stored on the server.

You can get data from database using PHP and it will return.So i advice to you using php from C# like api.