# Can i Connect Visual Studio 2017 to a Free 000webhost MySql Database?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, phpmyadmin, web-hosting

I downloaded my Connectors and Tried to Test my connection through Server Explorer >connect to database >choose MySQL as new connection > and when I test connection error failed as I cannot reach the database , somehow maybe my server name or password is wrong i tried everything but still did not work, when i saw some of answers online they said i can't connect to a FREE webhost so my questions are :

1-can i connect to a free 000webhost MySQL database ?
2-if yes , how can i fill in the write server name , user name and password to test connection ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10505952/9105725

Comment: start with a mysql tool like mysqlworkbench...the parameters you enter there are what make up your connection string

Comment: @Ctznkane525 ok i will thank you , what after that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use MySQL Workbench to connect to the database, that way you will be able to easily import/add the necessary database/tables/data. Also, make sure your IP address is allowed to connect to the database. The database might not accept connections of unknown IP-addresses for security reasons. After allowing your IP you should be good to go.

Comment: ok i am downloading MySQL workbench , how does it work on 000webhost ?

Comment: Okay so I did some further research and it seems that a free plan does not allow ANY kind of remote connection, you can only use your database from the PHP scripts that are running on your 000webhost server. (thanks to this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/44172446/9198859)

EDIT: Even more research has been done: https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/connection-string/67069/3 the moderator answer on this points also states that a free plan is limited to PHP access to the database.

Comment: yes , i saw some of the users asked about it they said FREE is not available only through php script , thank you for you information.