# Can connect to mySql server via php but not with c#

Tags: c#, mysql

As I wrote in the topic, this works totally fine:

```
mysql_connect("server","username","password");
```

But this doesn't:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection connection =
   new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("SERVER=server;DATABASE=database;UID=username;PASSWORD=password;");
connection.Open();
```

The exception is always

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

And no, the question is neither a duplicate, nor answered [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505952/c-how-to-form-a-correct-mysql-connection-string)

Comment: Try replacing `server` with `localhost`

Comment: I already tried it, same exception...

Comment: check if database server is up.

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/ - `PASSWORD` should be `pwd`. Better yet use `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` so you don't have to worry about the details of the connection string, as per the answer in the question that I'm about to mark this a dupe of.

Comment: I just tried to connect with using the StringBuilder but the same error still appears...

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation, this

```
"SERVER=server;DATABASE=database;UID=username;PASSWORD=password;"
```

should be

```
"SERVER=server;DATABASE=database;UID=username;PWD=password;"
```

Comment: I tried the string on another database server and it worked fine there...