# How to make MySQL database connection class using MVC architecture in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make simple program using MVC architecture in C# but I can't send values to database. I have no idea how to make a controller class.

[image: MVC image] This is my database connection class:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
namespace MVC
{
    public class DBConnection
    {
        private MySqlConnection connection;
        private string server;
        private string database;
        private string uid;
        private string password;

        //Constructor
        public DBConnection()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        //Initialize values
        private void Initialize()
        {
            server = "localhost";
            database = "neelas";
            uid = "root";
            password = "root";
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
            database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        }
```

Comment: check the following topic Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505952/c-how-to-form-a-correct-mysql-connection-string

Comment: i'm trying to set the connection using MVC architecture.database class do not support