# "Keyword not supported" MySQL C#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I am developing a WinForms application in c# and MySQL (server from GearHost) for data storage. Now, I created a class to deal with SQL operations but everytime I call it my code throws the error "KeyWord not supported". I've read other similar questions but found nothing that works with my code.

```
string connectionString = @"datasource=mysql#.gear.host;port=3306;username=######;pwd=##########;database=########;";
MySqlConnection databaseConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
```

Comment: This might have an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10505999/2524589

Comment: It is a good piece of info as ConnectionStringBuilder does sound awesome but it keeps providing me the same error.

Comment: Could you also post the code in question? Or is the constructor throwing the error?

Comment: @KSib it is the constructor rest seems fine

Comment: @KSib today I woke up and retried the solution you've sent me using string connection builder and it worked. I must have done a upsy somewhere. Now it works! Can you please post as answer so that i can mark it?

Comment: I've added it. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the a connection string builder so you don't have to worry about mis-typing any of the keywords.

```
var conn_string = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
conn_string.Server = "######";
conn_string.UserID = "#######";
conn_string.Password = "#######";
conn_string.Database = "#######";

using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(conn_string.ToString()))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
     cmd.CommandText = "your command text";
     conn.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
string connectionString = @"datasource=mysql#.gear.host;port=3306;username=######;pwd=##########;database=########;";
```

Go with:

```
string connectionString = @"server=mysql#.gear.host;port=3306;uid=########;password=########;database=########;";
```

More examples here: https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: I used https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/ for my first attempt and it didn't do the trick. But it is solved now i used string builder as suggested in comments and today it worked. Bugs work in mysterious ways .... Or I screwed up... maybe the latter...