# how to mysql database connection string dynamically in c# asp.net

Tags: mysql, asp.net

how to set connectionStrings set dynamically such as store variable?

ex: `string id=root;password=sample;`

```
<connectionStrings> 
    <add name="Myconnection" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=root;password=sample;database=sample" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: With code. This isn't code, it's a configuration setting. In your application write code that changes the user and password.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to form a correct MySQL connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505952/how-to-form-a-correct-mysql-connection-string)

Comment: Although it would probably be a LOT safer if you used only one restricted account to connect to the database and used the already available authentication, authorization, user profile mechanisms to store users, their roles and permissions.