# Can't Connect with MySql, .Net Core Api

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, ado.net

I'm new to this and I can't connect my API with my data base, i'm using `.Net Core 3`, `MySql Server 8.0.18`, also I downloaded the Connector/Net 8.0.18 and visual studio 2019. This is my string connection:

```
"Server=localhost,3306;Database=portaldb;user=****;password=****"
```

My Startup.cs :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString(Defaultconnection);
        var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc => { 
            mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
        });
        var mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod();
                });
        });
        services.AddSingleton(mapper);
        services.AddTransient<IDbContext, PortalContext>();
        services.AddTransient<ISqlRepository, SqlRepository>();
        services.AddDbContext<PortalContext>(options => options.UseMySQL(connection));
    }
```

My DbContext:

```
public class PortalContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public PortalContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    private DbSet<UsersModel> Users { get; set; }

    private DbSet<CandidatesModel> Candidates { get; set; }

    private DbSet<UserTypesModel> UserTypes { get; set; }

    private DbSet<CompetenciesModel> Competencies { get; set; }

    private DbSet<JobsModel> Jobs { get; set; }

    private DbSet<SkillsAssessmentsModel> SkillsAssessments { get; set; }

    private DbSet<SkillSetModel> Skills { get; set; }

    ///some methods
}
```

Here are some screenshots of the usings of my DbContext and the packages that I installed, i'm not sure if those are the right ones or if i'm not using them in the correct way.

[Usings of my DbContext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtlEU.png)

[Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjq5J.png)

[MySql installations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhT71.png)

Right now i'm getting this error

> "Internal connection fatal error."

I tried with different connection string getting differents errors and I tried to search for an answer but there's almost no information with `MySql`, a lot with `Sql server` but no with `MySql`.

**Edit**
I change the string connection and the startup but i'm still getting an error

```
: 'Method 'get_Info' in type 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Infraestructure.MySQLOptionsExtension' from assembly 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=8.0.18.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' does not have an implementation.'
```

**Edit 2**
Ok i read that `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3` it's not compatible with `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore for Entity Framework - 8.0.18`so i did a rollback to the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1` and now i'm getting `Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.`

Comment: That's not a MySQL connection string

Comment: That's a SQL Server connection string. Even there, `Trusted_Connection=True` means Windows Authentication which is incompatible with a username/password

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to form a correct MySQL connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505952/how-to-form-a-correct-mysql-connection-string)

Comment: `options.UseSqlServer(connection)`??

Comment: ok i change the connection string to `"Server=localhost,3306;Database=portaldb;user=****;password=****"` and this line in the startup `services.AddDbContext<PortalContext>(options => options.UseMySQL(connection));` but it say's that i don't have the method `get_Info` implemented

Comment: downgrade your EF core version to match your MySql provider, until the error gone

Comment: Use Pomelo.EntityFramework.MySql for compatibility with .NET Core 3.0 / EF Core 3.0: https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql#compatibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, as  Panagiotis Kanavos mentioned i was using a wrong connection string so i change it to:

```
Server=localhost;Database=portaldb;user=***;password=***
```

also as  Dongdong said i was using `options.UseSqlServer(connection)` instead of `services.AddDbContext<PortalContext>(options => options.UseMySQL(connection));`

And with that i just have to change some versions, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3` it's not compatible with `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore for Entity Framework - 8.0.18`, i did a rollback to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1` and now it works.

Comment: As you discovered, MySql.Data isn't compatible with EF Core 3.0. If you want to use EF Core 3.0, switch to Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql: https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql#compatibility

Answer (score 0):

MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore supports and is only compatible with EF Core 2.1. For EF Core 3.0 or the latest version use Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql