# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root '@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

Hope you all are doing well! 
    I am facing some challenge while connecting with mqsql database.
    I am using springboot for developing the application and below is my code.
    #Controller
    -----------------------------------
    package com.springBoot;

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class JdbcController {
     @Autowired  
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;    
        @RequestMapping(path="/insert")  
        public String index(){  
            jdbcTemplate.execute("insert into user1(name,email)values('Rakesh','rakesh.fsm@gmail.com')");  
            return"data inserted Successfully";  
        }  

}

----------------------------------
#my SpringBoot configuration
application.propert
---------------------------------------------------
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql1 
spring.datasource.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
spring.datasource.username=root  
spring.datasource.password=system  
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
---------------------------------------------------------------
# Issues:
I am facing issues while connecting with MySQL database.And I am getting below error.

2020-01-31 23:56:42.654  INFO 1964 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-01-31 23:56:42.659  INFO 1964 --- [           main] c.springBoot.SpringBootJdbcApplication   : Started SpringBootJdbcApplication in 4.374 seconds (JVM running for 5.253)
2020-02-01 00:07:51.851  INFO 1964 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-02-01 00:07:51.852  INFO 1964 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-02-01 00:07:51.904  INFO 1964 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 52 ms
2020-02-01 00:07:52.034  INFO 1964 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-02-01 00:07:55.429 ERROR 1964 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root  '@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:354) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:202) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) [HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:554) [HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) [spring-jdbc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116) [spring-jdbc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79) [spring-jdbc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:371) [spring-jdbc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:418) [spring-jdbc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.springBoot.JdbcController.index(JdbcController.java:14) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) [spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) [spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) [spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) [spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) [spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) [spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_221]

2020-02-01 00:07:55.476 ERROR 1964 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root  '@'localhost' (using password: YES)] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root  '@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:354) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:202) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:554) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:371) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:418) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.springBoot.JdbcController.index(JdbcController.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_221]
```

Can you please let me know why I am getting this error? how I can solve this issue

### I am getting this error while connecting to the MySQL DB

Comment: check if the server is running,

Comment: You probably is passing the wrong user/password to mysql, as the error says. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505952/how-to-form-a-correct-mysql-connection-stringTake a look at

Answer (score 3):

when you receive `Access denied for user 'root  '@'localhost' (using password: YES)` it means that the application was able to connect to the running MySQL server, but the authorization step failed.

Please check if you are able to connect using another tool(you can type in the terminal `mysql -u root -p`). If you fail to connect, it means your credentials are incorrect, or your user is not allowed to connect to the target database.

If you are able to connect using another tool, the problem is that your application is loading another set of credentials(ex. if they are set on your OS environment).You can put a breakpoint and check if the correct credentials are loaded.

Comment: In my case it was couple of white spaces in spring boot  application.properties after password. Always thought it trims strings... Two hours of checking everythingg....